# Using 'in' in English

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, relative-clauses

> The bar in Barcelona which I met my wife in is still there.

What does 'in' in the relative clause of this sentence mean?
To understand this what subjects should I study?

Comment: The speaker met his wife in a bar. The bar was in Barcelona. The sentence is clumsily expressed; it would be more natural to say _The bar in Barcelona where I met my wife..._

Answer (score 2):

This subject in grammar is called *deferred prepositions*. There is below the essential of what  is useful to know about it, as shown in § 9.6 of CoGEL.

> (**CoGEL § 9.6**) Normally a preposition must be followed by its complement, but there are some circumstances in which this does not happen.
> In the following three cases the DEFERMENT of the preposition is obligatory.
>
> (a) Passive constructions with a prepositional verb where the subject
> corresponds to the prepositional complement in the active […]:
> • Has *the room* been paid *for*?
> • ∼ Has X paid *for the room*?
> • ≁ <sup>*</sup>Has *for the room* been paid?
> • She was sought *after* by all the leading impresarios of the day. [also in
> premodification : 'a much *sought-after* singer']
> • He was not paid attention *to*.
>
> (b) Infinitive clauses with thematization of the prepositional complement
> […]:
> • He's impossible to work with.
>
> (c) *-ing* clauses with thematization:
> • He's worth listening to.
>
> With interrogative and relative pronouns as prepositional complement, there are often alternative positions available: one formal with the preposition
> in its normal place before the complement [1, 2], the other informal with the
> preposition deferred to final position [1a, 2a]:
>
> WH-QUESTIONS […]:
> • At which house did you leave the car? < formal >  [1]
> • Which house did you leave the car at? [1a]
>
> Usually […]:
> • Where did you leave your car? [1b]
>
> RELATIVE CLAUSES […]:
> • The old house *about which* I was telling you is empty. < formal > [2]
> […]
> • The old house (which) I was telling you about is empty.
> [2a]
>
> A prejudice against such deferred (or 'stranded') prepositions [1a, 2a]
> remains in formal English which, for direct or indirect questions and for
> relative clauses, offers the alternative of an initial preposition [1, 2]. The
> alternative construction is often felt, however, to be stilted and awkward,
> especially in speech. In some cases, such as the following, the deferred
> preposition has no preposed alternative:
>
> • *What* did she look *like*?
> • *What* I'm convinced *of* is that the world's population will grow to an
> unforeseen extent.
> • *All* she could talk *about* was her dog.
>
> In general, it is the most common and the short prepositions which can be
> deferred, in particular spatial prepositions […], compare:
>
> • He left his coat *in the car*.
> ∼  . . . the car *in which* he left his coat
> ∼ . . . the car (*that*) he left his coat *in*
>
> • He left politics *because of the election results*.
> ∼ . . . the election results *because of which* he left politics
> ∼ . . . <sup>*</sup> the election results (that) he left politics *because of*
>
> • The plane was destroyed *through the pilot's carelessness*.
> ∼ . . . the pilot's carelessness *through which* the plane was destroyed
> ∼ . . . <sup>*</sup> the pilot's carelessness ((*that*) the plane was destroyed *through*

CoGEL     *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*
∼            systematic correspondence between structures
≁            no systematic correspondence between structures
<sup>*</sup>             unacceptable

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> The bar **in which** I met my wife, is still open.

But when you mention the location, in this case Barcelona, it is more natural to use the relative pronoun *where* =

> The bar **where** I met my wife is **in** Barcelona and it is still open.
>
> The bar **in** Barcelona, **where** I met my wife, is still there.

However, as FF mentions in the comments, there is nothing wrong with the following:

> The bar in Barcelona, **in which** I met my wife, is still open.

Maybe I have misunderstood the OP's question but I think it revolves around "in". The preposition **in** is used with/without names of streets, villages, towns, cities, countries and continents.

That bar is *in* Las Ramblas which is *in* Barcelona.
Barcelona is a city *in* Spain, a country *in* Europe.

Comment: I don't understand *as soon as you mention its location.* Are you suggesting we must change ***in which*** to ***where*** simply to avoid two instances of ***in*** in the same sentence? There's nothing wrong with *The bar **in** Barcelona **in which** I met my wife...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is nothing wrong with "in which", but it is felt to be formal, and that deters speakers from using it.

Comment: You can use commas and then the nonsense (that would be felt in a plain context) disappears. "The bar in which I met my wife **,** in Barcelona **,** is still open."

Comment: @LPH  oh yes, thanks.